# Failed to resolve 'com.github.bashizip:business-hours-picker:v1.1.0'

Tags: android, github, gradle

I am having a strange issue. I am adding this library for Business Hour Picking.

https://github.com/bashizip/business-hours-picker

But strangely the older versions are added with no issues. But when I add the latest one it is not resolving by gradle.

I have tried:

- Clean Project
- Rebuilt It
- Invalidate Cache & Restart

But i can't add the library.

I have also posted the issue on the github issues section.

Here is my Project Level Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // Android Navigation Safe Args Classpath


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: If you want to have that version specifically, the tag seems to have been stuffed up on the repo. It's actually `v.1.1.0` (notice the additional `.` after the `v`), so you would put `implementation 'com.github.bashizip:business-hours-picker:v.1.1.0'` in your dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the newest version of the library (1.1.1):

```
 implementation 'com.github.bashizip:business-hours-picker:1.1.1'
```

It has many improvements, bug fixes and Gradle dependencies have been upgraded.

PS: I'm the author of the lib.